# Scaling ImageView Programmatically

Tags: imageview, scale

I have 7*7 ImageViews and I want to put them scalingly in some positions.
I need to know how I scale ImageView and how to set their position relatively to screen size.
(I will need to reposition and animate them dynamically after program start)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a CGAffineTransormation onto the image view

```
  imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(CGFloat sx, CGFloat sy);
```

This will scale down the image view, and will give you your desired output

Dealing with the repositioning, all you gotta do is add a CGAffineTransformationTranslation

```
  imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(CGFloat tx, CGFloat ty)
```

Do this with all the image views that you watn, and you will get what you want

Hope this helps!

Comment: Should I import something for this transform. Because transform is marked red and says "transform cannot be resolved or is not a field" ?

Comment: you might need to import the CoreGraphics.framework for that.